# Can't import bootstrap

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, bootstrap-sass

I've looked through many solutions but  still can't find the solution to my problem. I'm using Rails 5.0.0.1, running on Windows OS. I've done bundle install and restarted the server, as well as downgrading the sass-rails but I can't seem to fix the issue.

The gems I needed for this:
    bootstrap-sass <3.3.7>
    sass-rails <5.0.6, 3.2.0>

In my application.scss file:

```
 @import "bootstrap-sprockets";
 @import "bootstrap";
```

In my application.js file:

```
 //= require jquery
 //= require jquery_ujs
 //= require turbolinks
 //= bootstrap-sprockets
 //= require_tree .
```

[The error page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KiMg2.png)

Please help! Thanks!

EDIT 
Here is my Gem list:
(It didn't use to have two versions but I think I might have messed it up some how when I downgraded sass-rails and then installed the autoprefixer-rails gem for a different solution I found.)

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

`actioncable (5.0.0.1)
actionmailer (5.0.0.1, 4.2.6)
actionpack (5.0.0.1, 4.2.6, 3.2.
actionview (5.0.0.1, 4.2.6)
activejob (5.0.0.1, 4.2.6)
activemodel (5.0.0.1, 4.2.6, 3.2
activerecord (5.0.0.1, 4.2.6)
activesupport (5.0.0.1, 4.2.6, 3
arel (7.1.2, 7.1.1, 6.0.3)
autoprefixer-rails (6.5.3)
bigdecimal (default: 1.2.6)
binding_of_caller (0.7.2)
bootstrap-sass (3.3.7)
builder (3.2.2, 3.0.4)
bundler (1.13.6, 1.12.5)
byebug (9.0.5)
coffee-rails (4.2.1, 4.1.1)
coffee-script (2.4.1)
coffee-script-source (1.10.0)
concurrent-ruby (1.0.2)
debug_inspector (0.0.2)
erubis (2.7.0)
execjs (2.7.0)
gem-path (0.6.1)
globalid (0.3.7)
hike (1.2.3)
i18n (0.7.0)
io-console (default: 0.4.3)
jbuilder (2.6.0)
journey (1.0.4)
jquery-rails (4.2.1)
json (1.8.3, default: 1.8.1)
loofah (2.0.3)
mail (2.6.4)
method_source (0.8.2)
mime-types (3.1)
mime-types-data (3.2016.0521)
mini_portile2 (2.1.0)
minitest (5.9.0, 5.4.3)
multi_json (1.12.1)
nio4r (1.2.1)
nokogiri (1.6.8 x64-mingw32)
pkg-config (1.1.7)
power_assert (0.2.2)
psych (default: 2.0.8)
puma (3.6.0)
rack (2.0.1, 1.6.4, 1.4.7)
rack-cache (1.6.1)
rack-ssl (1.3.4)
rack-test (0.6.3)
rails (5.0.0.1, 4.2.6)
rails-deprecated_sanitizer (1.0.
rails-dom-testing (2.0.1, 1.0.7)
rails-html-sanitizer (1.0.3)
railties (5.0.0.1, 4.2.6, 3.2.22
rake (11.2.2, default: 10.4.2)
rdoc (4.2.2, default: 4.2.0, 3.1
rubygems-update (2.6.8)
sass (3.4.22, 3.1.21)
sass-rails (5.0.6, 3.2.0)
sdoc (0.4.1)
spring (1.7.2)
sprockets (3.7.0, 2.2.3)
sprockets-rails (3.2.0)
sqlite3 (1.3.11 x64-mingw32)
test-unit (3.0.8)
thor (0.19.1)
thread_safe (0.3.5)
tilt (2.0.5, 1.4.1)
turbolinks (5.0.1)
turbolinks-source (5.0.0)
tzinfo (1.2.2)
tzinfo-data (1.2016.6)
uglifier (3.0.2)
web-console (3.3.1, 2.3.0)
websocket-driver (0.6.4)
websocket-extensions (0.1.2)`

Comment: Can you add your Gemfile to your question too. Also do `gem list` just as a sanity check that `bootstrap-sass` is actually there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After adding @import "bootstrap-sprockets"; @import "bootstrap"; in your application.scss file, remove all the *= require_self and *= require_tree . statements from the sass file.